# Using Google IAM for GKE service web access

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-identity, google-iam

I am hosting an application on GKE and would like to be able to let users from my organization access this application from the web. I would like them to be able to log-in using their Google Account IAM credentials.

Is there a way to configure a service exposing the clusters web endpoint such that to access this service the user simply needs to login with their google account?

For example, when testing a service I can easily do a web-preview in the cloud-shell and then access the web application in my browser.

Is there a way to configure this such that any users authorized in my organization can access the web interface of my application?

*(Note, I asked the [same question on DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/4886/8189) but I feel like that site is not yet as active as it should be so I ask here as well)*

Comment: I don't think it's built into GKE directly. We ended up doing this ourselves using https://github.com/bitly/oauth2_proxy and nginx ingress.

Comment: @Hitobat That seems like a promising option. Can you perhaps provide a fuller answer detailing the steps you took to configure the service?

Comment: To be honest we had a consultant set it up for us, so that's as much as I know offhand. I'll try to find the docs they left but hopefully knowing the software used will give you a Google-able starting point.

Comment: I found this blog post which looks pretty promising: https://blog.billyc.io/2018/03/25/deploying-and-using-oauth2_proxy-to-google-kubernetes-engine/

Comment: I think I found what I am looking for here: https://cloud.google.com/iap/ Still haven't implemented, if it works I will update with an answer.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. The  Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy  (Cloud IAP) would be appropriate for your use case. After you configure Cloud IAP in your application, users will be able to access the web based authentication UI with their Cloud IAM identity. 

The users are subject to [the same refined](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/concepts-overview) granularity and access control as the Cloud IAM identities in the project. 

You can follow [these steps](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/enabling-kubernetes-howto) in the public documentation on how to setup Cloud IAP for Kubernetes Engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I managed to make it work perfectly. But it took a few steps. I am including the manifest here that is required to setup the [IAP](https://cloud.google.com/iap/) [using an ingress](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/enabling-kubernetes-howto). It requires a few things which I listed in the manifest below. Hopefully this can help others since I could not find a single source that had all of this put together. Essentially all you need to do is run `kubectl apply -f secure-ingress.yaml` to make everything work (as long as you have all the depenedencies) and then you just need to configure your [IAP](https://cloud.google.com/iap/) as you like it.

---

**`secure-ingress.yaml`**

```
# Configure IAP security using ingress automatically
# requirements: kubernetes version at least 1.10.5-gke.3
# requirements: service must respond with 200 at / endpoint (the healthcheck)
# dependencies: need certificate secret my-secret-cert
# dependencies: need oath-client secret my-secret-oath (with my.domain.com configured)
# dependencies: need external IP address my-external-ip
# dependencies: need domain my.domain.com to point to my-external-ip IP
# dependencies: need an app (deployment/statefulset) my-app
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-secure-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: my-external-ip
spec:
  tls:
  - secretName: my-secret-cert
  backend:
    serviceName: my-service-be-web
    servicePort: 1234
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-service-be-web
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    beta.cloud.google.com/backend-config:
      '{"default": "my-service-be-conf"}'
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: my-app
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 1234
      targetPort: 1234
      name: my-port-web
---
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1beta1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  name: my-service-be-conf
  namespace: default
spec:
  iap:
    enabled: true
    oauthclientCredentials:
      secretName: my-secret-oath
```